# Why is $\Bbb{Z_2} / \{e\} = \Bbb{Z_2}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups, solvable-groups

Let the group $\Bbb{Z_2} = \{e, a\}$. We are given the quotient group $\Bbb{Z_2} / \{e\}$. So this gives us a set of left cosets: $\Bbb{Z_2} / \{e\} = \{e\{e\}, a\{e\}\} = \{\{e\}, \{a\}\} \neq \{e, a\} = \Bbb Z_2$, but when my professor was explaining solvable groups, he said that $\Bbb{Z_2} / \{e\} = \Bbb{Z_2}$. I don't understand this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When he states equality, he actually means that the groups are isomorphic.

Comment: That's right, and one often conflates a group with the group mod the identity, because the cosets consist of one-element sets. But I'd like to praise the OP for being careful! My students have lots of problems with these sorts of considerations.